# python error not sure if it's bug or code problem

Tags: python

I am working on a school project. The the project is about making a basic school registration no data base just pure simple code. My problem is, there is a part in my code " EDIT STUDENT DATA " that  should let you change the data like NAME , ADDRESS , PHONE , EMAIL. I got the part where you can change the NAME but when I change the ADDRESS , PHONE , EMAIL  the program will terminate and give error messages. enter code here

Thank you in advance guys.

I have already double check the codes and I can't Identify where the problem is.

https://docs.google.com/document/d/1OEvXrzY3oI8CpNyJPJmITHCcDi6613LXoqj7fRJfW7k/edit?fbclid=IwAR1wdj6i8jmhZ5f4BCurFZhdLr_JylpNlTP4XrA78AGm7I_VaoSeVYOpEqo

this URL redirects to my code

Comment: I would ask you provide [mcve] and then if you link the code use ideone or repl.it

Comment: Why oh why oh why is your code on google docs? Why are your methods marked  as propertys? Why do you even need classes? Why you have so many globals?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is how you are storing your data and retrieving it. You seem to store your data in separate lists, but they share the same index. When you edit your data you forget this (`data` is the name of the person you are editing):

```
if (edit_num == '1'):
    new_value = input("Enter New Name: ")
    data_index2 = listStd1.index(data) # works because listStd1 has names
    listStd1[data_index2] = new_value
    print("Successful updated New Name is: ", listStd1[data_index2])
    return self.e_submenu()
elif (edit_num == '2'):
    new_value = input("Enter New Address: ")
    data_index2 = listAdd.index(data) # doesn't find because listAdd is addresses not names
    listAdd[data_index2] = new_value
    print("successful updated New Address is: ", listAdd[data_index2])
    return self.e_submenu()
```

If you look how your view data works you get the index of `data` in `listStd1` and use that to reference the other lists:

```
data_index1 = listStd1.index(data)
print("\n")
print("Data for Student: {}".format(data))
print("1-First name and last name: {}".format(data)) # data is name
print("2-Address: {}".format(listAdd[data_index1])) # reference index of data in listStd1
print("3-Phone Number: {}".format(listPhone[data_index1])) # ditto
print("4-Email-Address: {}".format(listEmail[data_index1])) # ditto
```

So the fix would be to maybe define `data_index2` outside of the if block and as it is defined in the first `if`

```
data_index2 = listStd1.index(data)
if (edit_num == '1'):
    new_value = input("Enter New Name: ")
    listStd1[data_index2] = new_value
    print("Successful updated New Name is: ", listStd1[data_index2])
    return self.e_submenu()
elif (edit_num == '2'):
    new_value = input("Enter New Address: ")
    listAdd[data_index2] = new_value
    print("successful updated New Address is: ", listAdd[data_index2])
```